# How can I tell bower where to install packages?

Tags: bower

I'm figuring out how to install packages using bower.

When I 'bower install packagename', packages are installed in /app/components/.

However, I'd like to dictate the structure of my projects myself.

Is there a way to configure bower to install packages in particular places?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bower can be configured using JSON in a [.bowerrc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1APq7oA9tNao1UYWyOm8dKqlRP2blVkROYLZ2fLIjtWc/edit#heading=h.4pzytc1f9j8k) file.
The directory setting is the path in which installed components should be saved.
If not specified it will be install in the default path.

So for example :

```
{
  "directory" : "package/components",
  "json" : "bower.json"
}
```

Here we tell bower to install packages in the subfolder `package/components`, and use a file named `bower.json` to store its data.